# NumberFormatException For input String: "9646324351"

Tags: java

Here's a snapshot of [a problem on LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-integer/):

[image]

For this problem, they provide this framework code you have to fill in:

```
public int reverse(int x) {
}
```

When testing solutions, it seems to provide an unreasonable input and won't let me submit my solution. The error is:

[image]

Note that the input is `1534236469`. That fits in an `int` as *input*, but the reversed version, `9646324351`, naturally doesn't, as the max positive value of an `int` in Java is `2147483647`.

Is this just an error in the LeetCode test? Or is there some trick I can't imagine that magically lets me return `9646324351`, a clearly out-of-range value, back from `reverse` as an `int`?

Here's my code, but the code almost doesn't matter, as the return type (`int`) is fixed by the problem (so by "integer" they really mean `int`, not `long`):

```
public int reverse(int x) {
    String intString;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if(x < 0){
        sb.append("-");
        x = x * -1;
    }
    intString = Integer.toString(x);
    for(int i = intString.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        sb.append(intString.charAt(i));
    }
    String resultString = sb.toString();
    int result = Integer.parseInt(resultString);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: It's too large. Use Long.parseLong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<s>This is an error in the LeetCode test.</s> There is simply no way to store the return value they're asking for in an `int`, thus no way to return it from `reverse` per the framework code provided.

<s>Perhaps the test cases were randomly generated across the full range of `int`, not taking into account that `reverse` can take the value out of range for an `int` for certain inputs.</s>

It turns out that they want you to return `0` if the reversed number would be out of range. Not that they bother to mention that anywhere in the problem.

Comment: *(Why this is a CW answer: I'm the one who reopened the question. I don't want any appearance of impropriety.)*

Comment: I finally got to the bottom of it. Apparently, that test case was introduced intentionally, and you're supposed to test for 32 bit int overflow and just return 0 whenever it happens. You can edit the answer for the sake of anyone else this might be useful to.

Comment: @ Fourth: Pathetic of them to have left that minor detail out! As that's not just not a reasonable thing to assume...

Comment: It's not a minor detail it's an important part of the specification that was apparently missing. The spec for a function / method should state what happens in the case where it's impossible to compute the answer, or (in this case) impossible to return the computed answer. Throwing an IllegalArgumentException would have been another option - but again - that should be stated in the specification. How can you write correct code based on assumptions?

Comment: @Rodney: Exactly. (I was being sardonic. :-) )

Comment: Yes but maybe not everyone gets your humour, and the issue caused a bit of a row on here - I thought it was worth pointing out that there's a flaw in the leetcode question. btw on the page It says "For the purpose of this problem, assume that your function returns 0 when the reversed integer overflows.", but - to see that text, you have to click "show spoilers".

Comment: @Rodney *"...but - to see that text, you have to click "show spoilers".* Grrrr. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I finished by follow method

```
    int result=0;
    try{
        result = Integer.parseInt(stringBuilder.toString());
        return result;
    }catch(Exception e){
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Long.parseLong()`. The number is too big for integer. The maximum value for integer is 2^31-1=2147483647.

Comment: he still wont be able to put the result into his variable because it it an int. The variable needs to be a long aswell instead of int

Comment: @Fourth There's no way that you're ever going to be able to put the number 9646324351 in an `int`, because the number is simply too big to fit in an `int`. If Leetcode requires that you put exactly this number in an `int`, then they've given you an impossible task.

Comment: I agree with @Jesper, the upper limit for an int is absolute in Java and it is 2147483647. If Leetcode requires this number to be an int, maybe the number is not 9646324351 and you have the wrong number.

Comment: @Jesper That impossibility is "the problem." Doesn't make any sense to me either, which is why I posted/edited. But unfortunately S.O has become a place where people are easily bashed for no utter reason. Thanks for the help though. I'll up vote your comment

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully submit the code but still I want to optimize in terms of running speed and space utilization.
Can you please share your thoughts on this.

```
class Solution {
    public int reverse(int x) {
        String reverse;
        if(x==0 && x > Integer.MAX_VALUE && x < Integer.MIN_VALUE){return 0;}
        if(x<0){
            x = Math.abs(x);
            String temp = String.valueOf(x);
            int len = temp.length();
            reverse = "-";
            for(int i=len-1;i>=0;i--){
                reverse = reverse + temp.charAt(i);
            } 
        }else{
            String temp = String.valueOf(x);
            int len = temp.length();
            reverse = "";
            for(int i=len-1;i>=0;i--){
                reverse = reverse + temp.charAt(i);
            } 
        } 
        try{
        int rev = Integer.parseInt(reverse);
        return rev;
        }catch(Exception e){return 0;}
    }
}
```

Runtime: 10 ms, faster than 8.10% of Java online submissions for Reverse Integer.
Memory Usage: 37 MB, less than 13.88% of Java online submissions for Reverse Integer.